# A double pin: does this count as check?

Tags: rules, check, pins

I was thinking about this position.

```
[FEN "4k3/8/4q3/8/8/8/8/2K1Q2r b - - 0 1"]
[startflipped ""]
```

Can the Black queen move to another file? If she moves then there is nothing blocking the White queen from checking Black king. But because the White queen is pinned, does this count as a check?

Comment: As always, forget about check for a moment, and imagine that the game is about capturing the enemy king. Then the black queen obviously cannot move from the file because white will play Qxe8 and the game is over. So in the game with check, that move is illegal.

Comment: For cases like these where you're not sure if a move is legal, a good way to check is to set up the position in a lichess analysis board (https://lichess.org/analysis). Then if you try to make the move, lichess should prevent it if the move is illegal. Doesn't require an account too, which is convenient.